# Remover aspas simples javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace

Preciso remover aspas simples de uma string, já tentei `string.replace(/\'/g, '')`,
`.replace(/"'"/g, '')` e não funciona, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Podes mostrar um exemplo da string?

Comment: Não vejo problema com o replace, provavel que não esteja re-atribuindo, dessa forma: `string.replace(/\'/g, '')` deve ser `string = string.replace(/\'/g, '')`, porque o replace em si não altera a string.

Comment: Seria algo como isso:

` dataVencimento: '{$gte:ISODate("2017-11-09T02:00:00.000Z")}'`

Preciso remover as aspas simples antes de `{$gte` e depois de `)}`

Comment: O teu código funciona para essa string... https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/jefwatnk/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas utilizando o [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) é o suficiente:

```
var a = "joao's empreendimento";
var b = a.replace(/'/g, '');
console.log(b);
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/85bnxq5x/

Comment: O código ao AP funciona. Acho que o problema é outro...

Comment: Testei dos 2 jeitos e o código sugerido pelo @Everson funcionou, agradeço imensamente a ajuda de todos

Comment: @LeonardoEbert Agradeço o retorno e que bom que tenha lhe ajudado ;)